# Polymorphism between a parent and a child class

Tags: java, spring, polymorphism, visitor-pattern

I'm developing with the Visitor pattern, like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractVisitor {
    public void visit(AbstractConfig config) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

which is inherited by

```
@Component
public class ConcreteVisitor extends AbstractVisitor {
    public void visit(ConfigA config) {
        // Do something
    }
    public void visit(ConfigB config) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Where, of course `ConfigA` and `ConfigB` extend `AbstractConfig`.

I use the bean instance of `ConcreteVisitor` by autowiring it like this:

```
@Autowired
private AbstractVisitor visitor;
```

The problem is, when I call `visitor.visit(config)`, where `config` is an instance of `ConfigA`, it raises a NotImplementedException.

Now I declared all of possible abstract methods into `AbstractVisitor`, but is there another preferable solution? I mean, a concrete visitor can define any methods polymorphic to the argument of parent's abstract method.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: replace this: public void visit(AbstractConfig config) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    } with: public void visit(AbstractConfig config); and make sure that your autowiring wires an implementation of the correct class

Comment: @Stultuske, thank you for your comment, but that didn't work, still raises the error.

Comment: That's also one of the reason why `@Override` is important: It save you from problem like this that you thought you have overridden a method but actually not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`public void visit(AbstractConfig)` is not the same as `public void visit(ConfigA)`. If you have an `AbstractConfig` and call `visit`, parent's method will be called.

```
AbstractConfig con = new ConfigA();
visitor.visit(con); //NoImplementedException (parent's method)

ConfigA = conA = new ConfigA();
visitor.visit(conA); //OK, ConcreteVisitor's method
```

You have to declare each method for each concrete implementation of `AbstractConfig`. Use an interface for the visitor instead:

```
public interface Visitor {
    public void visit(ConfigA config);
    public void visit(ConfigB config);
}

@Component
public class ConcreteVisitor implements Visitor {

    @Override
    public void visit(ConfigA config) {
        // Do something
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(ConfigB config) {
        // Do something
    }
}

@Autowired
private Visitor visitor;
```

Comment: thank you for replying, but that way doesn't allow us to define another method, say `visit(ConfigC config)`, `visit(ConfigD config)` etc...

Comment: You're right, that is because the usage of visitor pattern has to be very justified. Each time you want add new `AbstractConfig` implementation, you have to add a method to the `Visitor` interface and implement it in `ConcreteVisitor`

Comment: I get the picture. What I'd like to do is a bit different(It'd be better if I can substitute another implementation bean flexibly), but that means using the Visitor pattern is not preferable, right? I'll remain my code as you suggested. Thank you @bigdestroyer